# Compound assignment operator overloading

Tags: c++, vector, operator-overloading

I have seen Boost give you the possibility of doing:

v*=c  where c is i.e. a double and v is a vector

How could I make, as an exercise, the overloading of *= correctly, which works in the same way of the previous example (with double on the right side)?

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this?

```
// in class
T& operator *= (double d)
{
   member *= d;
   return *this;
}

// outside of class
T operator * (T v, double d)
{
   v *= d;
   return v;
}
```

Comment: You're missing an `=` in the second example

Comment: @maja it's not example, it's overloading of `operator *` just for consistence.

Comment: Then your code is modifying the parameter v, which shouldn't happen when you write `v1 = v * 4.2;`

Comment: @maja it's copy, real object will not be modified.

Comment: Damn, you're right. pass-by-value. Embarrassing that I didn't see it.

Answer (score 0):

Your method will look as follows:

```
inline vector operator *= (vector v, double &b);
```

It's overloaded for the class vector, should take a double, should modify the object itself and should return itself to be used as `v1 = v2*= 4.2;`

Since it's for an exercise, you won't post the implementation here.